# Read a file after updating contents within the file

Tags: node.js, nodes

I have created three methods as below in Node JS

```
function UpdateJson(reqData){
  let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('someData.json'); 
  let data = JSON.parse(rawdata);

  Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
    data[key] = reqData[key];
  });

 fs.truncateSync('someData.json', 0, function(){});
     let jstrData = JSON.stringify(data);
     fs.writeFileSync('someData.json', jstrData, function(){});
 }

function CreateThemeScss(jFile){
    fs.createReadStream(jFile)
    .pipe(jsonSass({
      prefix: '$theme: ',
    }))
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('sData.scss'));
}

function ExecuteCmd(){
  exec('node-sass sData.scss styles.css');
  var rdata = fs.readFileSync('styles.css').toString();
  return rdata;
}
```

I am using calling these methods in app.post method as in the same sequence.
I am sending back the returned `rdata` from `ExecuteCmd` method in the response.

I see that every time i call the API `rdata` from the `ExecuteCmd` method is same. I want these above methods to execute synchronously, so that `CreateThemeScss` executes only after `UpdateJson` is complete and `ExecuteCmd` must only execute after `CreateThemeScss` is complete so that i get the updated `rdata` in my response.

Any kind of help is welcome

Comment: It should help if you provide us how do you call these methods.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In app.post. I call these method in sequence. As in UpdateJson("{"test":"test"}"); CreateTheme(dJson.json); var a = ExecuteCmd();

Answer (score 0):

First, you need [Stream NodeJS documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html).

What i understand from your issue is that the `CreateThemeScss` function call remains asynchronous, because `jsonSass` gives you a `stream` object.

But you seem to want to wait the end of `CreateThemeScss` stream before executing `ExecuteCmd`.

This is how we could do if it is the issue :

```
function UpdateJson(reqData) {
    const rawdata = fs.readFileSync('someData.json'); 
    let data = JSON.parse(rawdata);

    Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
        data[key] = reqData[key];
    });

    // fs.truncateSync('someData.json', 0, function(){});
    // is wrong called, see https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_ftruncatesync_fd_len

    fs.truncateSync('someData.json', 0);
    const jstrData = JSON.stringify(data);

    // fs.writeFileSync('someData.json', jstrData, function(){});
    // is wrong called, see https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options

    fs.writeFileSync('someData.json', jstrData);
}

function CreateThemeScss(jFile) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const readStream = fs.createReadStream(jFile);

        readStream.on('error', reject);

        readStream.on('end', resolve);

        readStream
            .pipe(jsonSass({
                prefix: '$theme: ',
            }))
            .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('sData.scss'));
    }
}

function ExecuteCmd() {
    exec('node-sass sData.scss styles.css');
    // return rdata
    return fs.readFileSync('styles.css').toString();
}
```

And call it this way :

```
...
UpdateJson("{'test':'test'}");
await CreateTheme(dJson.json);
var a = ExecuteCmd();
...
```